# substrate: missing generics for struct `pallet_democracy::GenesisConfig`

Tags: pallet, rust

When attempting to build the Democracy pallet (`pallet_democracy`) within a runtime based on the `polkadot-v0.9.15-1` branch, built native using Rust stable `1.57` and WASM using Rust nightly `2021-11-29`, this build error appears with little assisting information.

```
error[E0107]: missing generics for struct `pallet_democracy::GenesisConfig`
    --> runtime/alpha/src/lib.rs:1177:1
     |
1177 | / construct_runtime! {
1178 | |     pub enum Runtime where
1179 | |         Block = Block,
1180 | |         NodeBlock = primitives::Block,
...    |
1247 | |     }
1248 | | }
     | |_^ expected 1 generic argument
     |
note: struct defined here, with 1 generic parameter: `T`
    --> /usr/local/cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/e6fbbd5/frame/democracy/src/lib.rs:479:13
     |
479  |     pub struct GenesisConfig<T: Config> {
     |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ -
     = note: this error originates in the macro `construct_runtime` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
help: add missing generic argument
     |
1177 | GenesisConfig<T>
     |

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0107`.
error: could not compile `native-runtime-alpha` due to previous error
```

**Contents of `runtime/alpha/src/lib.rs`**

```rust
#![cfg_attr(not(feature = "std"), no_std)]
#![recursion_limit = "256"]
#[cfg(feature = "std")]
include!(concat!(env!("OUT_DIR"), "/wasm_binary.rs"));
[...]
impl pallet_democracy::Config for Runtime {
    type Proposal = Call;
    type Event = Event;
    type Currency = Balances;
[...]
    type ExternalOrigin = pallet_collective::EnsureProportionAtLeast<_1, _2, AccountId, CouncilCollective>;
    type ExternalMajorityOrigin = pallet_collective::EnsureProportionAtLeast<_1, _2, AccountId, CouncilCollective>;
    type ExternalDefaultOrigin = pallet_collective::EnsureProportionAtLeast<_1, _1, AccountId, CouncilCollective>;
    type FastTrackOrigin = pallet_collective::EnsureProportionAtLeast<_2, _3, AccountId, TechnicalCollective>;
    type InstantOrigin = pallet_collective::EnsureProportionAtLeast<_1, _1, AccountId, TechnicalCollective>;
    type InstantAllowed = InstantAllowed;
    type FastTrackVotingPeriod = FastTrackVotingPeriod;
    type CancellationOrigin = EnsureOneOf<
        AccountId,
        EnsureRoot<AccountId>,
        pallet_collective::EnsureProportionAtLeast<_2, _3, AccountId, CouncilCollective>,
    >;
    type CancelProposalOrigin = EnsureOneOf<
        AccountId,
        EnsureRoot<AccountId>,
        pallet_collective::EnsureProportionAtLeast<_1, _1, AccountId, TechnicalCollective>,
    >;
    type BlacklistOrigin = EnsureRoot<AccountId>;
    type VetoOrigin = pallet_collective::EnsureMember<AccountId, TechnicalCollective>;
[...]
    type OperationalPreimageOrigin = pallet_collective::EnsureMember<AccountId, CouncilCollective>;
    type WeightInfo = pallet_democracy::weights::SubstrateWeight<Runtime>;
    type MaxProposals = MaxProposals;
}

[...]

/// The type used to represent the kinds of proxying allowed.
#[derive(Copy, Clone, Eq, PartialEq, Ord, PartialOrd, Encode, Decode, RuntimeDebug, MaxEncodedLen, scale_info::TypeInfo)]
pub enum ProxyType {
    Any,
    NonTransfer,
    Governance,
    Staking,
    IdentityJudgement,
    CancelProxy,
}
impl Default for ProxyType { fn default() -> Self { Self::Any } }
impl InstanceFilter<Call> for ProxyType {
    fn filter(&self, c: &Call) -> bool {
        match self {
            ProxyType::Any => true,
            ProxyType::NonTransfer => matches!(c,
[...]
                Call::Democracy(..) |
[...]
            ProxyType::Governance => matches!(c,
[...]
                Call::Democracy(..) |
[...]
            )
        }
    }
}
[...]
construct_runtime!(
    pub enum Runtime where
        Block = Block,
        NodeBlock = primitives::Block,
        UncheckedExtrinsic = UncheckedExtrinsic
    {
[...]
        Democracy: pallet_democracy::{Pallet, Call, Storage, Config, Event<T>},
[...]
    }
);
```

**Contents of `node/src/lib.rs`**

```
use sc_service::ChainType;
use sp_core::{ed25519, Pair, Public};
use sp_runtime::traits::{IdentifyAccount, Verify};
use native_alpha::{
    AccountId, AuthorityDiscoveryId, AuthorityDiscoveryConfig, BabeConfig, BalancesConfig, BabeId,
    CouncilConfig, ImOnlineId, IndicesConfig, GenesisConfig, GrandpaId, GrandpaConfig, SessionConfig,
    StakingConfig, Signature, SystemConfig, TechnicalCommitteeConfig,
    BABE_GENESIS_EPOCH_CONFIG, WASM_BINARY
};
pub type ChainSpec = sc_service::GenericChainSpec<GenesisConfig>;
[...]
fn testnet_genesis(
    wasm_binary: &[u8],
    initial_authorities: Vec<(
        AccountId,
        AccountId,
        BabeId,
        GrandpaId,
        ImOnlineId,
        AuthorityDiscoveryId,
    )>,
    root_key: AccountId,
    endowed_accounts: Vec<AccountId>,
    _enable_println: bool,
) -> GenesisConfig {
    GenesisConfig {
[...]
        democracy: Default::default(),
[...]
    }
}
```

Now, it seems that the `construct_runtime` macro generates `GenesisConfig` which is then extended with `sc_service::GenericChainSpec` to give us the `ChainSpec` type, which is then used by the node.

We are using other pallets that do require a `GenesisConfig` (such as `pallet_grandpa`) but don't have similar errors as merely uncommenting calls to `pallet_democracy` bypasses the problem altogether.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than:

`Democracy: pallet_democracy::{Pallet, Call, Storage, Config, Event<T>},`

Add in `<T>` to the Config here:

`Democracy: pallet_democracy::{Pallet, Call, Storage, Config<T>, Event<T>},`

or if you're ok having all of the exports of that pallet you can just say:

`Democracy: pallet_democracy,`

(This second syntax is fairly new which is why it's not as prevalent)